# Problems with Scale Animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, view, scale

I'm trying to scale a view (a ListView) to a certain size when the user clicks on an item in the ListView. The ListView's "original" (beginning) state is set to

```
layout_width="match_parent"
```

The ListView is obviously a rectangle, if you will. I can't figure out how to scale down the ListView and keep the left side of the rectangle(ie. ListView) "anchored" to the left side of the screen/parent-activity. All I want to happen is the ListView's right side to slide in from the right side of the screen/parent. The y-axis is not to be scaled or changed, only the right side of the ListView. I apologize if this isn't clear enough. Below is a crude picture of the beginning state and end state of the ListView upon a user click.

[a busy cat http://dc589.2shared.com/download/mdK_EobN/listviewanimationjpeg.jpg?tsid=20130313-093629-3c816601](http://dc589.2shared.com/download/mdK_EobN/listviewanimationjpeg.jpg?tsid=20130313-093629-3c816601)

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are certain that you always have the expanded view first, then you could do something like this:

1. start by using match_parent as you currently do, to ensure it take up all the horizontal space of its parent container.
2. Override `onWindowFocusChanged` of your activity to get the maximum required width

   ```
   @Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
       // myComponentToBeResized.getMeasuredWidth(); 
   }
   ```
3. Store 50% of this value, so, you have the width of both the fully expanded and partially expanded view.
4. Update your view to use pixels (or dip) as width, instead of the match_parent keyword. Now, you can animate between the two values as you see if :)

Comment: Forgive me if I don't fully understand and/or my question was not exactly clear, however just thinking about the answer you provided won

Answer (score 0):

you can try `relativeLayout` and in this layout use your `ListView` add `android:alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:alignParentTop="true"`to your `ListView` then try using the scale animation on listView.By adding these attributes your `listView` will be like fixed to the left side.hope it works.